Query on dependency version
In my Spring Boot application, I have used Spring Boot version:
<version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>

and also MySQL connector dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

Note that no version is mentioned for this dependency, meaning it inherits version from parent pom.
I changed Spring Boot version to 2.7.18, but I see that now Maven complains about MySQL dependency version missing, and I have to modify dependency as:
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.32</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

What's the reason for this behaviour?

There is a (very long) list with changes since 2.0.4-release (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/compare/v2.0.4.RELEASE...v2.7.18 ), at least one of them talks about spring-boot-dependencies manages mysql:mysql-connector-java which no longer exists
